# ReferenceError: functionxyz is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having an error that kinda makes me upset atm. I have three script files, one jQuery, another one including all my functions and the last one is a file where I use one of the function in the functions-script-file.

```
    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/assets/web/js/jquery/de.jq.311.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/assets/web/js/func.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/assets/web/js/sign/signup.js"></script>
```

Signup.js now tells me that a certain function that actually is defined in func.js is not defined, even tho they are all in the correct order and I have checked it twice, the function is spelled the right way. I also have tried to put the functions directly in the head tag above the signup.js and that worked just fine.

func.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // VARS
    var body = $('body');


    // FUNCTIONS
    var dialerTimeout;
    function showDialer(text) {
        var t  = text;
        clearTimeout(dialerTimeout);
        var rd = $('response-dialer');
        rd.find('.inr p').html(text);
        rd.css('bottom', '12px');

        dialerTimeout = setTimeout(function(){ rd.removeAttr('style'); }, 3000);
    }
});
```

signup.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', '[data-action="signup"]', function(){

        var mail  = $('input[name="mail"]').val();
        var pass  = $('input[name="password"]').val();
        var pass2 = $('input[name="password2"]').val();
        var agb   = $('input[name="agb"]').val();
        var rd    = $('response-dialer');
        var lc    = $('login-container');

        console.log($('[data-form="signup"]').serialize());

        if(mail === '' || pass === '' || pass2 === '') {
            showDialer('Bitte fülle alle Felder aus!');
        } else if(pass !== pass2) {
            showDialer('Ihre Passwörter stimmen nicht überein!');
        } else if(grecaptcha && grecaptcha.getResponse().length === 0) {
            showDialer('Der Captcha-Code ist falsch!');
        } else if(!($('#agb').is(":checked"))) {
            showDialer('Bitte lese und akzeptiere unsere AGB!');
        } else {

            if(!validateEmail(mail)) {
                showDialer('Ihre E-Mail hat ein falsches Format. Bitte nutze name@host.endung');
            } else {

                addOverlay(lc);

            }

        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Please add relevant code. We can't help if we can't see your code.

Comment: Yeah I am sorry, added it

Comment: `function showDialer` is defined within a function, and is not available outside that scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the error because `showDialer` is only in the scope of the callback passed to `$(document).ready` in `funcs.js`. In order to use it in another script, you have to either define it as a global function, or (better) combine your 2 scripts into one file with just the one `$(document).ready` enclosing everything.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your scope. You're defining the `functionxyz` within the `$(document).ready()` scope within the first file, which means it's unavailable to the second file, even though their "scope" is the same (`document.ready`).

You need to define the function you want outside of the `document.ready` scope so that it can be globally accessed by the `signup.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are wrapping each one of them in a separated `$(document).ready` function which explains that behavior.

If you don't really need the `$(document).ready` function for a specific purpose, I would recommend to **remove it from both of them** and your code will work just fine. But, in case you need it for any reason, just **wrap both files together under ONE `$(document).ready` function** so that you can access it without any scoping issue!

For more information about Scope in Javascript, feel free to check this [Scope Guide from Scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript)